# Button click to render textarea giving error

Tags: angular, button, input, angular-material, angular-ng-if

I have a button which when clicked , should render a textarea. I am using Angular Material. Tried using ngIf in the textarea tag but giving errors -

> **Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.**
> I have added the library , so I think its the ngIf that is causing the issue.Wrapping textarea tag inside ngcontainer tag and using ngIf in it, gives this error as well.
> HTML

```
        <button  mat-raised-button color="primary" (ngSubmit)= "toggleTextBox()">
            Add 
        </button>  
        <form [formGroup]= "limitationForm">  
          <mat-form-field > 
            <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>            
            <textarea matInput *ngIf= "showTextBox" formControlName="limitTextarea"  
             type="text"  id="limitTextarea" name="limitTextarea" ></textarea>                   
        </mat-form-field>   
       </form>
```

Ts

```
toggleTextBox() {
    this.showTextBox = !this.showTextBox; 
}
```

Comment: you're right, it is the *ngIf that is causing the issue.  You can either put the *ngIf directive on the mat-form-field (which would change the UI)

or you can just hide the textarea (and not actually remove it from the dom `<textarea [hidden]="!showTextBox">,` `<textarea [style.display]="showTextBox ? null : 'none'">`, etc.

Comment: I have added in the mat-form-field as  <mat-form-field *ngIf= "showTextBox" >  but nothing happens and no error. What am I missing? When you said would change UI, what do you mean please?

Comment: I meant the UI will be different than your original attempt, as now your label is going to be hidden because it is wrapped in the *ngIf.

If you want the label to always show, you will have to hide the textbox with css, rather than *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use *ngIf on the `<mat-form-field>` itself, instead of on the `<textarea>`:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="toggleTextBox()">Add</button>

<form [formGroup]="limitationForm">
  <ng-container *ngIf="showTextBox">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput formControlName="limitTextarea" type="text" id="limitTextarea" name="limitTextarea"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you imported it correctly try to make two versions from mat-form-field one with textarea and the second without it to avoid changing the style and get rid of the error.

```
<button  mat-raised-button color="primary" (ngSubmit)= "toggleTextBox()">
  Add 
</button>  
<form [formGroup]= "limitationForm">  
<mat-form-field *ngIf= "!showTextBox"> 
  <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>            
</mat-form-field>   
<mat-form-field *ngIf= "showTextBox"> 
  <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>            
  <textarea matInput  formControlName="limitTextarea"  
   type="text"  id="limitTextarea" name="limitTextarea" ></textarea>                   
</mat-form-field>
```